# How to create a directory and save data using Download Manager in Micro sdcard - android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-download-manager, android-storage

I am developing a app from which user can download the videos, currently the code stores in the sdcard but I want to store in micro sdcard due to memory issue. I have not seen any question on SO which guide me to store data in micro sdcard.

Comment: What is the difference between sdcard and micro sdcard in terms of Android coding

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. `DownloadManager` and your app do not have any place on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) that both apps can access, and AFAIK `DownloadManager` has no means to work with removable storage directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare if storing data intro micro sdcard is not possible then how torrent does the same?

Comment: @AjinkyaS sdcard: internal storage, micro sdcard: memory card

Comment: Storing data on removable storage is possible, as I outlined in [the blog post that I linked to from my original comment](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You are asking to have `DownloadManager` download to removable storage, and AFAIK that is not possible. A BitTorrent client will not be using `DownloadManager`, as `DownloadManager` has nothing to do with BitTorrent.

Comment: @CommonsWare we set the destination directory while downloading with `Download Manager`. can't we set the destination of micro sdcard directory while downloading?

Comment: No. The downloads that you request via `DownloadManager` are downloaded by *a separate app*. At most, you can provide a destination directory that *your app* can work with, but `DownloadManager` will not be able to use that directory, because *it is not your app*, and each app's directory on removable storage is only accessible to that app. You are welcome to download the information by some other means: OkHttp, `HttpURLConnection`, etc.

Comment: I hope this helps you saving on micro sdcard (memory card)
http://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file

Also handle the permission on Marshamallow and above device